# Unable to find Service Fabric application New project option in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-service-fabric, azure-hub

**Solution :**

> From answers we were able to find the location on Window 7 :
>   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
>   Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

I am  following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-quick-start) .
For creating a new Service Fabric application I need to select the following application in image :

[image]

But on my computer I am not able to find the same option :
[image]

I have installed the [SDK from here for VS 2017](http://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/webpi.ashx?command=getinstallerredirect&appid=MicrosoftAzure-ServiceFabric-CoreSDK)  , but then too I am unable to find an option for new Service Fabric application .

Please tell what I am missing.

I have Powershell 3.0 , VS 2017 Community Edition, Windows 7

Installed components : 
[image]

Comment: Why you've runned blend for vs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Service Fabric Tools are part of the Azure Development and Management
>   workload in Visual Studio 2017. Enable this workload as part of your
>   Visual Studio installation.

This means that you need to run installer again and make sure that you've selected azure deployment
[image]

In addition you are running blend no visual studio 
[image]

PS. Can you please verify that you've installed it?

[image]

Comment: I have installed Azure development from installer already , please check updated question for image . Is this right option ?

Comment: @Softxide yes but you have installed or you need to modify it?

Comment: This is my first install , I only need to create a Service Fabric application.Even the local cluster of service fabric is up , which means i Have SDK  for same ?

Comment: @Softxide you installed right. But I see you are running Blend for Visual Studio. Run Visual Studio pls

Comment: How to run VS 2017 ?  In all programmes I can only find Blend so I thought thats a new IDE for 2017 . :)

Comment: @Softxide hit windows button type visual studio :) it must show you:)

Comment: I can only find Blend or some internet links , I am trying to search directory for exe file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152808/discussion-between-volodymyr-bilyachat-and-softxide).

Answer (score 1):

Enable Azure Development workload in visual studio 2017 as follows:
Go to Tools > Get Tools and Features. Under Workloads, make sure to, select Azure development.

In addition,you need to install the Microsoft Azure Service Fabric SDK and runtime using Web Platform Installer.

Finally,Close visual studio and start it as an administrator.

[image]

For more info see link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started